# How to check hyperlink status after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I retrived data from database in form of dynamic list with hyperlink.
Now I want to check whether  the link is already clicked or not .If it
is clicked already I want to display that link Italic Otherwise (not
clicked) display that link Bold while loading data from database.

Mycode  for dynamic list with hyperlink:

```
    $("div").append("<li  id='list' >"+"<a id='link' class='delete'
href='javascript:link()'>" +
   results.rows.item(i).StudentName +  "</a>"+ "<hr/>"+ "</li>");
 function link(){
                          $(".sidemenu li ").click(function() {
                                $(".sidemenu li a").css('font-style' , 'italic');
                                $(this).find('a').css('font-style' , 'normal');
                 });
        }
```

I want to when I run the application again and again I should get this
clicked link in Italic (I get normal link again run that
application)..

so how to check link status (ie,link is clicked or not) by using that
status get clicked link in italic .after refreshing the page.

Please kindly guide me.Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to check the link status after refreshing page (after getting info from database) ?

Comment: yes sir.Is it possible? How to check link status? please guide me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jQuery [plugin](http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin/) for finding visited links?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have used this plugin and i am getting the blank browser.But my problem is if i run the application again, the already visited link should be normal and new link should be in bold.Please kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Because these are purely style changes why not use the CSS property `:visited`?  It would look something like this:

```
a:visited {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$("div li").click(function(){ 
   $("div li a").css('font-style' , 'normal');  
   $(this).find('a').css('font-style' , 'italic');  
});
```

have good time :D

Comment: Thank you Sir,It works fine.But when I run the application again I should get this clicked link in Italic (I get normal link again run that application).Please kindly guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: no put this code in your $(function () { /*this code*/ }); and its worked true;

Comment: I have added  that code in $(function () { /*this code*/ });It's not work pleaseguide me

Comment: oh, i am so sorry, i forget after refreshing the page in code, If you can use the cookie in your website, when click on `li` you can send ` $(this).find('a').attr('id or anything')` in to your cookie if you can not try with cookie, say to me to insert that code here for you,

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How to use cookie?Please kindly guide me.

Comment: check out this link: http://www.webmuse.co.uk/projects/jcookie-jquery-plugin/  use this cookie with jquery lib.